# How to pass the curl --insecure alternative when using R?

Tags: r, curl, httr

How can I download [this file](https://www.stf.jus.br/arquivo/djEletronico/DJE_20171123_266.pdf) with R and save it to disk?

I have managed to download it already using `curl` on the command line by adding the `--insecure` flag to it. But I cannot figure out how to do it in R.

This is the command line way:

```
curl https://www.stf.jus.br/arquivo/djEletronico/DJE_20171123_266.pdf --insecure --output ~/Desktop/test2.pdf
```

Comment: It'd be better for a whole host of reasons to try to update the CA database on your system.

Comment: @hrbrmstr thanks, I thought the problem was related to the server. How should I go about updating the CA database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `curl` library:

```
library(curl)

URL <- "https://www.stf.jus.br/arquivo/djEletronico/DJE_20171123_266.pdf"   
h <- new_handle()
handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifyhost = 0, ssl_verifypeer=0)

curl_download(url=URL, "file_test2.pdf", handle = h)
```